# divs appearing in wrong order (vertically)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to mark up a header, a title for the webpage and a navigation bar as depicted below:

[image: proposed layout]
My problem is that they aren't appearing in this order. I can successfully create the header, page title and even the items of the navigation bar. But if I try to create a background for the navigation items by wrapping a div around the navigation items and adding a background color, the box sits on top of the page title such that it looks like this:

[image: current layout]

How do I get the navigation box to sit where the navigation menu options are (as in the first pic)?

Here's my code:

```css
/* HEADER */

header .headerBox {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

header .name {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .account {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* PAGE TITLE */

.page-title {
  width: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 80px 0 80px 0;
}

/* NAVIGATION BAR */

.navigationBox {
  background-color: rgba(80, 120, 180);
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}

.menu-item {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 120px 0 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <!-- HEADER -->

  <header>
    <div class="headerBox">
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><span class="name">Company name</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="account.html"><span class="account">Account</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- PAGE TITLE -->

  <div>
    <section class="page-title">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->

  <div class="navigationBox">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="menu-option-1.html"><span class="menu-item">Menu Option 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="menu-option-2.html"><span class="menu-item">Menu Option 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add clear:both to your CSS as such:

```
.navigationBox {
  clear:both;
}
```

The **clear property** is used to specify that which side of floating elements are not allowed to float. It sets or returns the position of the element in relation to floating objects. If the element can fit horizontally in the space next to another element which is floated, it will.

**Syntax:**

```
clear: none|left|right|both|initial;
```

The **clear:both** means floating elements are not allowed to float on the both sides.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learning. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is using `float` without any clearfix. I just fixed the code: https://jsfiddle.net/n2w0h7da/

CSS

```
/* HEADER */

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

header .headerBox {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

header .name {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .account {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* PAGE TITLE */

.page-title {
  width: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 80px 0 80px 0;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}

/* NAVIGATION BAR */

.navigationBox {
  background-color: rgba(80, 120, 180,1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}

.menu-item {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 120px 0 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

HTML

```
  <!-- HEADER -->

  <header>
    <div class="headerBox">
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="name"><span>Company name</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="account.html" class="account"><span>Account</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- PAGE TITLE -->

  <div class="clearfix">
    <section class="page-title">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->

  <div class="navigationBox">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="menu-option-1.html" class="menu-item"><span>Menu Option 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="menu-option-2.html" class="menu-item"><span>Menu Option 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is slightly more confusing for a newbie like me but I feel like this is a better answer.

Comment: Although as I understand it, old browsers don't support the double-colon syntax.